# How to Add Emoticons into Forum

Tags: html, wamp, forum, emoticons

Is there a simple code that can add emoticons into our text in forum by just using php or html or any other languages suggestions?
I use wamp server.

Comment: What forum? Not enough information

Comment: Most forums come with them pre-installed, they may just be disabled somewhere in your settings. However agreed – not enough information.

Comment: yes phpbb forum has that code.

Comment: I mean a simple forum like a discussion forum built for our website and this forum was created with php coding.The thing is to add emoticons or smiley while typing the text.

Comment: hakre  can please post me the link of which code you meant before!!!